# mandar un valor por url y que este recorra en un bucle for PHP

Tags: php

```
  echo '<p class="price">$'.$precio.'</p>';
  echo '<p class="buttons">';
  echo '<a href="detail.html" class="btn btn-default">Ver 
          Detalle</a>';
   // input donde ingreso cantidad
  echo '<input type="number" name="ja" value="0" id="jaa" class="la 
   ma">';   
  //boton donde mando el id para posterior consulta                                     
  echo '<button value="'.$id.'" class="boton_compra">Añadir 
         Carrito</button>';
```

funcion js con la cual mando por url el id y la cantidad

```
  function anade(){
  var fila = $(this).parents("p");
   if(fila.find(".ma").val() >0){
   $("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?p="+$(this).val());
   $("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?
   c="+fila.find(".ma").val());
```

en el php poncarrito pongo esto

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['p']; 
$_SESSION['contador']++;
}
f(isset($_GET['c'])){
$_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c']; 
}
for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION['contador']; $i++){
  //esto es lo que nose si estoy bien mal o que onda con la cantidad
  // que ingreso 
  $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1];
  $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
  id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
  echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" 
  value='.$cab.'></center>';
?>
```

hasta en estas no tengo problema pero cuando quiero mandar la cantidad que ingreso en el input tengo todo tipo de problemas porque si capturo la variable que contiene el valor del input todos los productos se ponen con la misma cantidad y no se como hacer que recorra ya hice unos cuantos intentos y el resultado fue este: mirar foto...se ponen las cantidades pero cada cierto aumento de productos me queda en blanco la cantidad mi pregunta es como haria para capturar al cantidad y que recorra el bucle sin problemas ya que cuando lo hice le puse a la variable que entra con el indice $i del bucle y el resultado fue el de la foto ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67485/discussion-on-question-by-vinicio-moya-almeida-mandar-un-valor-por-url-y-que-est).

Comment: y de casualidad no tienes alguna respuesta o algo que me puedas ayudar con el tema

Comment: Voy a mirar la pregunta a ver si puedo ayudar. Pero te comento: debes completar el [tour] y leer [ask] para ver cómo funciona el sitio y cómo mejorar tus publicaciones. En lugar de crear/borrar preguntas, deberías editar para añadir la nueva información.

Comment: si soy nuevo y esoty en proceso de aprender a como preguntar o como moverme aqui pero por si acaso  solo puse el codigo relevante a la pregunrta peor despeus todo esta cerrado y eso sino que sale muy extenso